# select min and max depending of a flag

Tags: sql, max, min, flags

So I have this table "dump" :

```
_____________________________________
| id_seller | client | price | flag  |
|====================================|
|     1     |   a    |  12   | True  |
|     1     |   a    |  10   | True  |
|     1     |   a    |  13←  | True  |
|     1     |   a    |  14   | False |
|     1     |   a    |  9←   | False |
|     1     |   a    |  11   | False |
|     2     |   a    |  15←  | True  |
|     2     |   a    |  13   | True  |
|     2     |   a    |  14   | True  |
|     2     |   a    |  21   | False |
|     2     |   a    |  23   | False |
|     1     |   a    |  20←  | False |
|     1     |   b    |  14   | True  |
            [...]
```

I'm trying  to get the minimum and maximum price for some clients and sellers depending of the flag something like this :

```
_________________________________________________________
| min_price_flag0 | max_price_flag1 | client | id_seller |
|========================================================|
|         9       |       13        |    a   |    1      |
|         20      |       15        |    a   |    2      |
|         42      |       21        |    b   |    1      |
|         84      |       10.5      |    b   |    2      |
etc..
```

I'm using this request at the moment which works but I'm not sure if it's performant nor elegant , it also gives me trouble to join it with other select in aggregated tables:

```
SELECT min_price_flag0,
       max_price_flag1,
       client,
       id_seller
  FROM (
           SELECT min(price) AS min_price_flag0,
                  client,
                  id_seller
             FROM dump_table
            WHERE id_seller IN (1,2,3) AND 
                  client IN ("a", "b", "c") AND 
                  flag = "False"
            GROUP BY client
       )
       AS min_price_flag0_select
       INNER JOIN
       (
           SELECT max(price) AS max_price_flag1,
                  client,
                  id_seller
             FROM dump_table
            WHERE id_seller IN (1,2,3) AND
                  client IN ("a", "b", "c") AND 
                  flag = "True"
            GROUP BY client
       )
       AS max_price_flag1_select ON min_price_flag0_select.id_seller = max_price_flag1_select.id_seller AND 
                                    min_price_flag0_select.client = max_price_flag1_select.client
```

I'm not very good at sql and have very limited access to the databases so I'm looking for advices to better that select.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggragtion (`CASE WHEN`inside `MIN`/`/MAX`):

```
SELECT
  MIN(CASE WHEN flag = 'False' THEN price END) AS min_price_flag0,
  MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 'True' THEN price END) AS max_price_flag1,
  client,
  id_seller
FROM dump_table
WHERE id_seller IN (1,2,3)
AND client IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY client, id_seller
ORDER BY client, id_seller;
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks ! 
And sorry for the typo in the title